# Let $f(x)$ be Riemann-integrable, $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)dt.$ Then $F(x)$ is differentiable, and $F'(x)=f(x)$ almost everywhere.

Tags: real-analysis

> What is wrong with the following statement:
>
> Let $f(x)$ be Riemann-integrable, $$F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)dt.$$ Then $F(x)$ is differentiable, and $F'(x)=f(x)$ almost everywhere.

I think the statement is true. Because $f(x)$ be Riemann-integrable, it's continuous almost everywhere. Then by the [Second Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SecondFundamentalTheoremofCalculus.html), $F(x)$ is is differentiable almost everywhere, and $F'(x)=f(x)$ almost everywhere.

Comment: I think you should add something like this: "if $f:I \to \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable on the interval $[a,x] \in I$..."

Comment: The way it is written, it could be interpreted that $F$ is differentiable everywhere.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre yes, maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer: $f$ is Riemann integrable iff $f$ is bounded and continuous
almost everywhere (a characterization due to Lebesgue).

In elementary analysis, it is well-known that if $f$ is continuous
at $x$, then $F'(x)$ exists and $F'(x)=f(x)$.

Comment: Sorry, forget to mention that the domain of $f$ and $F$ under consideration is a closed and bounded interval.